# how to prevent scripts from being run

Tags: javascript, xss

SO kept preventing me from posting the title I wanted so finally got a title that let me post though it kind of sucks so feel free to edit/change it.

I have fields a user can fill in and in the javascript we have

```
'${chart.title}'
```

and stuff like that.  Is it sufficient to just strip out the single quote character such that they cannot escape it back to javascript?  or are there other ways to close out the string that started with the single quote character.

${chart.title} inserts the title a user typed in on a previous page so naturally they could type something like "Title'+callMethod()+'RestOfTitle" injecting a callMethod into my javascript.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Are you passing the input to the server? If you are, I believe that would be the place for a XSS filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to restrict the input to alphanumerical and space characters.

If you want to allow anything inside the title, you can use a escaping function.
http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Just stripping the string of single quote characters is definitely not enough. Think of new lines for one reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options.

First go very restrictive way and do both so called  [white-list validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet) for input field for you title and always encode the text that you output to the page. That will filtered out all unwanted (and potentially dangerous) characters and make sure that if some of them pass filter (or somebody update the text to contains some js code after the filters were applied) the encoding procedure make all malicious js scripts not runable (it turns it into plain text).

Second you do let your users input what ever they want (which is highly unrecommended way but sometime developers asked to do it) but always encode the text that you output to the page.

You can implement white-list validation by yourself using regular expression or you can use one of the libraries.